# Python/Pandas: How to break 2 column into separate records?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of stats of Pokemon (this is what the head looks):
[image]

I want to be able to make an analysis based on the type of the pokemon.  The problem I have is that there is a type_1 and a type_2 column.  I am interested in looking at the total stats by type irregardless if it is a type_1 or type_2.  How would I go about solving this?  My guess is that I would have to create a second row for each pokemon with it's type_2 as type and change the type_1 of the original record to type.  How do I go about doing this in Pandas?

Edit:  An example output of what I would be interested in is like this:
Grass: Average Hp: 300, Average Attack: 50, Average Defense: 60....
Poison: Average Hp: 308, Average Attack: 60, Average Defense: 40..
...

Comment: There are many ways, too many ways!  You'd be better served if provided an example of what you expected the final output to look like.

Comment: I edited the question, does that make sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Fire', 'Poison', 300, 30, 10],
        ['Poison', 'Grass', 250, 20, 15]
    ], columns=['Type1', 'Type2', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense'])

    Type1   Type2   HP  Attack  Defense
0    Fire  Poison  300      30       10
1  Poison   Grass  250      20       15
```

Use `pd.melt`

```
stat_cols = ['HP', 'Attack', 'Defense']
type_cols = ['Type1', 'Type2']
melted = pd.melt(df, stat_cols, type_cols, value_name='Type')
melted.groupby('Type')[stat_cols].mean()

           HP  Attack  Defense
Type                          
Fire    300.0    30.0     10.0
Grass   250.0    20.0     15.0
Poison  275.0    25.0     12.5
```

***extra credit***
*use `describe`*

```
stat_cols = ['HP', 'Attack', 'Defense']
type_cols = ['Type1', 'Type2']
melted = pd.melt(df, stat_cols, type_cols, value_name='Type')
melted.groupby('Type')[stat_cols].describe()


                      HP     Attack    Defense
Type                                          
Fire   count    1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
       mean   300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
       std           NaN        NaN        NaN
       min    300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
       25%    300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
       50%    300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
       75%    300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
       max    300.000000  30.000000  10.000000
Grass  count    1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
       mean   250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
       std           NaN        NaN        NaN
       min    250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
       25%    250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
       50%    250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
       75%    250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
       max    250.000000  20.000000  15.000000
Poison count    2.000000   2.000000   2.000000
       mean   275.000000  25.000000  12.500000
       std     35.355339   7.071068   3.535534
       min    250.000000  20.000000  10.000000
       25%    262.500000  22.500000  11.250000
       50%    275.000000  25.000000  12.500000
       75%    287.500000  27.500000  13.750000
       max    300.000000  30.000000  15.000000
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm now trying to get the pieces of data indivudally (to look at highest, lowest, etc of certain stats).  To do this I need a list of all the types.  I used you're following code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e03d51aad4fdf666744b2401982bdd8   and noticed that melted was giving NaN for some values.  Is there a reason for this and how do I fix it?

Comment: @TylerHilbert there is certainly a reason for this.  I don't know what that reason is without seeing exactly where the `NaN` data are.  It is best if you provided a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

So I think @piRSquared's is excellent. If you want the output to look exactly like your question though, try this:

```
types = set(df["Type_1])
types.add(df["Type_2])
data_columns = ["HP, "Attack", "Defense"]
for type_ in types:
    avgs = df[(df["Type_1"]==type_) | (df["Type_2"]==type_)][data_columns].mean()
    response = """{type}: Average Hp: {hp}, Average Attack: {attack},
               Average Defense: {defense}""".format(type=type_, hp=avg["HP"], 
                                                    attack=avg["Attack], 
                                                    defense=avg["Defense"])
```

Comment: There are 19 different types.  Is there a way to automate that for each time rather than hard code it?

Comment: Probably. Like @piRSquared said, we'd need to see an example of what you expect the output to look at.